# Melhorar a linguagem Visual Basic do editor de código nativo

Tags: bug, status-intencional, edição

Comparei o editor de códigos da linguagem Visual Basic nativo do Stack Overflow original e o deles é muito mais avançado que o nosso. Pelo simples motivo de:

```
'Isso é um comentário em Visual Basic, mas nosso editor considera como uma
'string em outra linguagem.
Dim kkkk = "ABC"
'Lalala
Dim ABC = kkkk
```

e também destacar as Keywords do Roslyn, seria uma boa.

Poderiam melhorar nosso editor?

Comment: Seria legal se você colocasse um link para uma pergunta no site principal onde nota que ocorre o problema descrito acima. Aqui no meta o syntax highlight não vai funcionar.

Comment: Só adicionar as keywords NameOf iria ajudar...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu acho que você está falando [desta resposta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80267). Se for isso mesmo, a formatação está incorreta porque a pergunta tem também a tag [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), e o código está sendo formatado como se fosse C#.

Você pode forçar a formatação correta na sua resposta inserindo a marcação `<!-- language-all: lang-vb -->` antes do primeiro trecho de código.

Fora isso, se bem me lembro, a Stack Exchange não faz customizações no highlighter de código-fonte, então acho que dificilmente incluirão uma nova keyword como você sugeriu.

Comment: Ah, não tinha reparado o detalhe das tags... Obrigado.